# Nginx WordPress Permalink Issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, nginx, centos

I have a Nginx based VPS with WordPress blog hosted on it. Its a Centos 7.

I have issues with custom permalink.
My current site `.conf` looks like this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|

ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching plugin (if used).
#include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;
#include global/wordpress-w3-total-cache.conf;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I am able to use permalink structure as :
`www.example.com/%post-name%`

I want to use it like :
`www.example.com/download-%post-name%-online`

When I save my custom permalink structure and open any post, the permalink works fine i.e. it shows
www.example.com/download-whatsapp-online
in the address bar but the content actually shows up is the homepage.

It would be glad if someone could rectify my `.conf` mistake.
Thanks. Cheers.

Comment: Nothing to do with php.

Comment: @epodax Wordpress is PHP... You also need a web server in order to serve your PHP files. It could be either Apache, Nginx, Lighttpd, etc.